# Is there a unique homomorphism of $\mathbf Z $ into $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading Atiyah and Macdonalds's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*. On pages 30, they say that

> ii) Let $A$ be any ring. Since $A$ has an identity element there is a unique homomorphism of the ring of integers $\mathbf Z$ into $A$, namely $n \mapsto n\cdot 1 $. Thus every ring is automatically a $\mathbf Z$-algebra.

I wonder whether $1$ shoud maps to the identity element of $A$. Of course we do not consider the trivial map. I find a counter example: $\phi : \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z$ which maps $1$ to $(1,0)$. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Let's not forget Macdonald! Anyway, look at the definition at the top of pg. 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "homomorphism".

You might think of it as a definition (i.e. that $f(1) = 1$ and that's it), which is fine, but there is something deeper behind.

You can consider the category of *unital* commutative rings, and in this category, the morphisms are ring homomorphisms which map $1$ to $1$ (since in some sense, we want the morphisms to respect the structure of the category, that is, that the rings are unital). You can apply the forgetful functor from the category of unital commutative rings to the category of commutative rings (by simply "forgetting that $1$ is there"), e.g. a unital commutative ring is in particular a commutative ring.

You have seen that this forgetful functor is not full, i.e. between two unital rings, there might be some ring homomorphisms which are not homomorphisms of unital rings. If the codomain ring is a unital integral domain, since 
$$
f(1) = f(1^2) = f(1)^2, 
$$
we see that $f(1) = 1$ or $f(1) = 0$. In the category of commutative rings (not necessarily unital), the option $f(1) = 0$ is a well-defined morphism, and in particular is the only extra morphism we obtain by forgetting that the rings are unital. However, in the more general case, you obtain more and more morphisms (for instance the one you found between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z^2$).

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Under a homomorphism of rings, $1$ should be mapped to the identity of $A$.

Comment: I tried a proof; if $A$ is an integral domain, $f(1^2)=f(1)$ implied $f(1)=1$ but if $A$ is not an integral domain, how can I know?

Comment: http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/ring-map/ring-map.pdf It depends on the axioms!

Comment: I got it. It's just a definition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Artin's book also requires $1 \mapsto 1$ in the definition.

Even without requiring this, the fact that homomorphisms preserve the ring operations guarantees that the homomorphism is completely determined by the image of 1:

Assuming $f: \mathbb{Z} \to A$ is a ring homomorphism, we have 
$f(n)=f(1+...+1)=f(1)+...+f(1)=nf(1)$, where the last equality is just notation (i.e. we define $n \in A$ to be the ring identity added to itself $n$ times).

However, if your ring is an integral domain (if for all $a, b \in A$, $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$), it is easy to prove that $f$ can only map 1 to the identity or to 0:

$f(n)=f(n\cdot 1)=f(n)f(1) \iff f(n)(1-f(1))=0$, which, if $A$ is an integral domain, implies $1=f(1)$ or $0=f(n)$. In that last case, since $n$ was arbitrary, $f $ is the zero map (so under Artin's definition, it would only be a ring homomorphism if $A=\{0\}$).

This is why your map preserves the operations, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, so 1 can be mapped to 1 or 0.

If you defined one (or both) of the coordinates to be something other than 1 or 0, $f$ would not be a ring homomorphism:

Say $f(1)=(1,2)$. Then using only homomorphism properties you can deduce that $(1,2)=f(1)=f(1 \cdot 1)=f(1)f(1)=(1,2)(1,2)=(1,4),$ so $2=4$, which is false (in $\mathbb{Z}$).

EDIT: A restriction on the image of 1 for arbitrary rings. If $f$ is a ring homomorphism, then $f(1)=f(1)f(1)=(f(1))^2$, so even for an arbitrary ring, $1$ can only be mapped to an element that squared is itself (an idempotent element), like $(1,0)$, in your example.